# Adjusting an Object on Center , works only when I determine width

Tags: html, css

Currently I'm working on sort of Images , I want them to be in Center of page So I'm using margin-left and margin-right set to auto to center it.
and here's the problem :

it does not work when i let browser find the width , if i set Width to auto , 
it'll be in left side of page

this problem can result responsibility problem , and makes page not compatible with Retina 
Here's My HTML code:

```
<div class="lang">
<a href="http://en.devcom.ir"><img src="english.png" title="Visit Our English Community" /></a><a><img id="shw" onClick="document.getElementById('box').style.display= 'block'" src="persian.png"/>
</div>
```

and CSS Class :

```
.lang {
margin-left:auto;
margin-right:auto;
width:96px;
height:32px;
margin-bottom:3px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with Css `flex` as follows:

```css
.lang {
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
  <a href="http://en.devcom.ir"><img src="english.png" title="Visit Our English Community" /></a>
  <a href="#"><img id="shw" onClick="document.getElementById('box').style.display= 'block'" src="persian.png"/></a>
</div>
```

For horizontal center alignment:

```css
.lang {
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="lang">
    <a href="http://en.devcom.ir"><img src="english.png" title="Visit Our English Community" /></a>
    <a href="#"><img id="shw" onClick="document.getElementById('box').style.display= 'block'" src="persian.png"/></a>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks , is this method usable whenever I want to adjust something in middle of page ?

Comment: @MohammadHoseinBin You wants images in one line? or in one column?

Comment: in one line , however I personalized the code how I want. is this way you said is most optimized way ? or anyway is ok?

Comment: @MohammadHoseinBin yes, It is optimized.

Answer (score 0):

#### Try this or Check fiddle

https://jsfiddle.net/g42rtk8s/7/

```
.lang {
display: block;
height: 32px;
margin-bottom: 3px;
text-align: center;
```

}

Comment: Thanks , but this is not optimized to set Display to inline-block and then set the Width to 100%